# Is it possible to make self updating application in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, auto-update

I am trying to make self-updating FX application. What I've managed to do is to separate dependencies in /lib directory and the main jar file in the root directory. I've also generated versions.xml file for those jar files in the /lib directory. With process explorer I've found out that the application which I launch uses every jar file, so for me it is not possible to overwrite them at runtime. 
I know I should use separate application for update process but how should I launch two separate apps and give them possibility to talk to each other or should I do so?
P.S. I know there is OSGI but I want only update functionality to be implemented.

Comment: Yes, see Java Web Start (JWS).

Comment: WebStart really is a pain to use. At least for serious deployment scenarios.  Take a look at GetDown perhaps (https://github.com/threerings/getdown).

Comment: No problems with WebStart here (its easy when application is signed (not self-signed!))

Comment: There was a discussion on the javafx-maven-plugin on this topic: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/288 ... self-updating comes with problems, but creating your own updater might be a valid option

Comment: Flagged as too broad. This has nothing to do with JavaFX and is strongly application-dependent.